# Spring social Twitter Api

Tags: twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am using spring social and the twitter api, Im able to get the connection working but cant find the way to retrieve the user's mail. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The Twitter API does not give you access to private information such as email addresses.